# CodeIgniter doesn't call a method, if validation in constructor fails

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to prevent a method from executing if validation in constructor fails. I'm using AJAX and I'm sending the request to a url like `example/search`. I'm currently checking if a variable isn't false but I think there's a better way of doing that, isn't there?

```
class Example extends CI_Controller {

        public $error;
        function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
                    //validation rules    
            if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
                $this->error=1;
            }

        }
        function search() {
            if(!$this->error) {
            //code
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: for which form you are checking validation in your constructor

Comment: Simple solution would be to move run() execution into search method, this depends if you're relying on this result in various other methods. You could also add a static property to run method (class containing run?) to store last result and return this if set but also you would need to reset it when data/rules change. You can also add isValid() that would encapsulate this logic inside... many ways to approach this. And yes public $error is pretty bad, as a minimum make it private.

Comment: There will be other methods, not only `search` and the form validation is always the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**application/config/form_validation.php**

```
$config = array(
     'search' => array(
        array('field'=>'', 'label'=>'', 'rules'=>''),
        array('field'=>'', 'label'=>'', 'rules'=>'')
     ),
);
```

-

**Controller**

```
public function search(){

   //is ajax request?
   if( !$this->input->is_ajax_request() )
   {
      return show_error('Bad Request!'); // bye bye, stop execution
   }

   $this->output->set_status_header('200');

   if( ! $this->form_validation->run('search') )
   {
      echo json_encode(array(
          'error' => 1,
          'errors' => array(
                'field' => form_error('field')
           )
      ));
      return; // bye bye, stop execution
   }

   //all good, continue executing
   //.....
}
```

**Edit**

```
//For just a constructor 

protected $isValidated = TRUE;

public function __construct(){

    //check for valid ajax request
    //do this in parent class(ajax_controller) ?

    if( !$this->form_validation->run('search') )
    {
       $this->isValidated = FALSE;
       return echo json_encode( array('error' => 1));
    }

    if($isValidated)
    {
         $this->_search( $this->input->post() );
    }
}

protected function _search( $input ){}
```

-

```
class Ajax_Controller extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct(){
       if( !$this->input->is_ajax_request() )
       {
          return show_error('Bad Request!');
       }

       $this->output->set_status_header('200');
    }
}
```

Comment: It still calls the method.

Comment: The Search method will be called regardless ! From OP code if(!$this->error)